# Debian doesn't boot anymore

Tags: debian, boot, lvm

I use Debian Wheezy.

Yesterday I added a new HDD to the system and expanded the LVM using the `system-config-lvm` gui-tool.

I have a logical LVM group for root, `/`, and one for home, `/home`.
I also installed updates.

Boot process:
[image: Boot process]

Windows 7 boots fine

How can I fix it?

Comment: The message on the middle of the screen is rather clear: a disk with that uuid could not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you did when you “expanded the LVM”. It seems that what you did required updating some values that Grub needs to locate the root filesystem: one of the hard disks has changed its identification.

While it is probably possible to boot your system by issuing the right commands at this prompt, this is pretty complex and difficult to explain without being in front of the machine. You'll have to locate the root device, mount it and run `/init` to switch to it.

I recommend booting from a rescue CD/USB. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) is a good choice. Activate and mount your system's root volume, then run the following commands in a terminal (with the root volume mounted on `/target`):

```
mount --rbind /dev /target/dev
mount --rbind /proc /target/proc
mount --rbind /sys /target/sys
chroot /target
update-grub
```

With your setup, I think this will result in a bootable system. If it doesn't, post the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: update-grub output
http://pastebin.com/0FjsZyFw


grub.cfg
http://pastebin.com/ZvfVZZPE


fstab
http://pastebin.com/73YaJjsY

Comment: Can he run `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` using the System Rescue CD to see what the UUIDs of his devices are?  Could his expansion changed the UUID of the partition?

Comment: The new hdd was missing in /boot/grub/device.map  


I used grub-mkdevicemap to generate a new one.  


Now I have a new error  
error: unknown LVM metadata header.  
http://pastebin.com/6ZGXSX0R

Comment: My system starts correctly now.

But how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not related to grub, but to the Debian initrd system. After grub load the initrd file system and the kernel, it run the kernel on a ramdisk with initrd. This initrd system include a series of command that should load you system.

One of the firsts step is to load all drivers, check for all hardware usable for booting, then looking for the device passed as ROOT parameter when grub started the kernel.

In your case, this ROOT device is not present, so you have a few options: one of them may be to extend the period the kernel wait in order to check for all sow devices. I don't think this is your case. So i assume you have some problem with your LVM configuration, and suggest to remove the new hard disk.

It is not clear if you expanded just the LVM group (adding a new phisical volume to the group) or if you also extended the LVM volume of root. In the first case, you may boot from a CD, reduce the group removing you new hard disk, and reboot.

If you extented your LVM root volume and resized that file system, you have to shrink the (unmounted) file system, then reduce the volume, then reduce the group and remove the new hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel isn't finding the filesystem for /. You can use tune2fs(8) to set the UUID of your new / to what it is asking here.